# Insert false data into database

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have multidimentions array hrefs :

```
Array
(

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://213b572-ba681bf9cc9e
        [1] => http://f057-4139-ac40-bc4449722ffc
        [2] => http://b-c151-4ba1-b7b7-842771c36d6b
        [3] => http://5a77fb-8fce-4793-868f-c9fd73524037
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://8-d832-4b34-a55b-da04ad8cdd09
        [1] => http://b38-6a60-4233-b207-f40fae2ef431
        [2] => http://3-f31c-49c4-87ee-fcada05a105f
        [3] => http://07514-e438-45e2-906e-b440cbcbf8dc
    )

......

[76] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://8-d832-4b34-a55b-da04ad8cdd09
        [1] => http://b38-6a60-4233-b207-f40fae2ef431
        [2] => http://3-f31c-49c4-87ee-fcada05a105f
        [3] => http://07514-e438-45e2-906e-b440cbcbf8dc
    )
```

When i insert array hrefs above into database

```
foreach ($hrefs as $id_page =>  $href) {
    foreach ($href as $value) {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO urls(`id`, `id_page`, `url`)
                    VALUES ('', '$id_page', '$value')");
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

I want my database are:

```
          | id | id_page | url |

          | 1    | 1       | http://jjjjjjjjj |

          | 2    | 1       | http://jjjjjjjjj|  
          | 3    | 1       | http://jjjjjjjjj| 

          ......

          | 1000 | 76      | http://jjjjjjjjj|
```

but result:

```
| id | id_page | url |

| 1    | 1       | http://jjjjjjjjj |

| 2    | 1       | http://jjjjjjjjj|  
| 3    | 1       | http://jjjjjjjjj| 

          ......
| 500  | 35      | http://jjjjjjjjj| 

|  501 | 1      | http://jjjjjjjjj|
```

When insert id_page loop to 35 and return begin 1.
$hrefs is multidimentions array like above. Any resolve?

Comment: could explain in detail about the problem , possibly with o/p you get and expected o/p?

Comment: @triMinh : your question is not very clear mate....can you try to explain a bit more - *i assume English is not your native language*

Comment: I was edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try it this way :

```
    foreach ($hrefs as $id_page =>  $href) {
        foreach ($href as $value) {
            mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO urls(`id_page`, `url`)
                        VALUES ('".$id_page."', '".$value."')");
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Assuming "id" is set to auto_increment in your table.

Edit1: Check your data type in your "urls" table: maybe your "id_page" is too small to hold big values. Set it to int(11) for example.

Edit2: If there is any performance issue, you should execute only one query with multiple values, like that:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO urls(`id_page`, `url`) VALUES ';
foreach ($hrefs as $id_page =>  $href) {
    foreach ($href as $value) {
        $sql .= "('".$id_page."','".$value."'),";
    }
}
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1); // delete last comma
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: :D, data type i set int(10), i don't think datatype is cause. id_page loop (1 - 76) length only 2.

Comment: It was just an idea. After your script run, every row in your database has id_page = 1 ?

Comment: No, ip_page run from 1 to 35 and return begin 1 - 35. I want id_page from 1 - 76. This is arrays. http://pastebin.com/2qXT8aEw. I use wamp 2. I think cause is wamp server.

Comment: ok weird ! why is it going back to value "1"? I would do some printing onscreen before executing your SQL. Something like : echo "INSERT INTO urls(`id_page`, `url`) VALUES ('".$id_page."', '".$value."')"."<br/>";

Comment: I run in cli and php file run to, when page_id = 35 it stop. When i run by browser php file stop and show blank page. I try get page_id  (1 - 35 ), browser show from 1 to 35. I think cause is mysql, i set connect_timeout but results is same.

Comment: maybe using mysqli_query only once out of the foreach loop is the solution (see edit2). slow php script can result in blank page. How long does your script take to execute ? You may need to add this on the first line : ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

Comment: Ok, Success, I ran script in morning. I ran my script about 15 minutes. I think problem is internet connecttion or wamp server. Thank's.